# Why didn't this bounty get awarded?

Tags: support, bug, bounties

I'm asking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21048265/2065121), on which a bounty was started on Jan 13 at 7:46

[image: start]

And which [I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21095920/2065121) on Jan 13 at 16:10 and the OP accepted as the best answer on Jan 13 at 19:34. So all of this happened within the active bounty period.

Then according to [the bounty help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), which says:

[image: help]

I think I should have been awarded the bounty by now. However, the question still shows this:

[image: ended]

Is there a time delay I'm not aware of here or is this a bug?

Comment: Give it some time, even grace period has a grace period. (yeah, it's weird)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok, but I gave it two hours ;-) I wish my wife had such a grace period ....

Comment: Nope, it's only hour and half right now, see the timestamps. From what I've seen, it's up to 2 hours so should happen any moment now. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The suspense is killing me .....

Comment: Yeeehaa ... it's happened .... :-))

Comment: Yup, 1 hour and 37 minutes grace grace period. :-)